# Route IP to another network without NAT

Tags: iptables, ip, routing, iptables-redirect

Hey I came up with the following Problem.
At my home I got one public IPv4 and want to add IPs.
I own multiple vServers with "as many" IPs I want. So I thought about buying an additional IP and routing it to my home router which then routes it to a NATed machine so that this is publicly adressable

I have server (Ubuntu for example) which has an interface called ens3. There is one public IPv4 assigned to it and another IP gets routed to this first IP:

XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX as primary IP and YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY as IP I want to route to my home router ZZZ.ZZZ.ZZZ.ZZZ.

At my home router I can simply add a static route which tells the router to send traffic for YYY... to a NATed machine - lets say 192.168.0.2 - and on this machine I assign ZZZ... to the interface. So I do not want to MASQUERADE on the machine XXX..

So here comes the part where my knowledge lacks a little. How to tell the machine XXX... to route the traffic for YYY.. to ZZZ... without even assigning YYY... to the interface itself? (iptables?)

I think the core of the question is, how does the home router implement the static route on the commandline?

Is here anyone who could give me a hint or tell me how to implement this?

Best regards!

Edit:
I created a small sketch (including subnet mastks and the actual router):
[image: overview]

I have to mention that this is more like a thought experiment. I realized that you have to route the return path as well.

I use a AVM FritzBox 7590 as edgerouter but it does not really matter because I don't think that this is capable of static routing from WAN to LAN. So it would work with this router anyway.

Comment: you'll probably need to use tunnels: the rest of Internet wouldn't know how to route between your server and your home router.

Comment: Okay I also think that should be the easiest method to implement this. I will have a try.

Comment: Note: using a tunnel between server and home server, rather than server and home router will add more routing challenges on the home server: now the home server must choose correct IP addresses *and* interfaces, and will probably need policy/source routing

Answer (score 0):

Technically it depends on what IP and subnet mask each of those IP's are on. Anyways, proxy arp may solve your issue. You should tell the router to act as proxy for the final machine's MAC address.

That is usually done with arp command. As your question lacks the details of the router, you have to look it up for your router's OS.

Comment: I added a sketch. xxx,yyy and zzz are in different subnets and publicly adressable.